# Changing the opacity of a div with a PHP 'while' loop

Tags: php, html, css, loops, while-loop

After a button is pressed in my PHP script, the header location is changed to another page. I was wanting to do something a bit more unique, and make the inputs fade out before the page changed. This is what I have so far:

```
$i = 10;
$i10 = ($i / 100);

while (i >= 1) {
    echo '<style>
        #loginForm {
            opacity: ' . $i10 . ';
        }
        </style>';
    $i--;
}
sleep(1);
header('Location: ../index.php');
```

The code does not seem to work. What would I need to do to achieve the intended effect? I would prefer to avoid any jQuery or JavaScript in my code.

Comment: You don't understand what PHP is for. You *must* do it in JavaScript, PHP has nothing to do here.

Comment: I understand perfectly what PHP is for. I was experimenting with it to see if it was possible to use it for effects.

Comment: Get prepared for Headers already sent errors...

Comment: The result of what your trying to do will just be last value of the loop, as all the php code is processed before the style tag is parsed.

Comment: I realize you can force refreshing page with reducing/increasing opacity, but IS THAT REALLY YOU WANT TO ACHIEVE?

Comment: As @TomaszKowalczyk already said this is definetely not PHP territory... You need to understand the difference between server side and client side scripting... If you dont want JavaScript, you can look at keyframe animations in CSS.

Comment: You **need** to use JavaScript for this one @Ryan.  You'll need to `preventDefault` to stop the page redirecting once the link has been clicked, then perform your animation, then force a redirect once the animation has completed.  

Personally I'd prefer pages to redirect quickly instead of sitting around whilst some animation fades out/in.

Comment: _“I understand perfectly what PHP is for. I was experimenting with it to see if it was possible to use it for effects.”_ – _had_ you understood it before, then you would have known that there is no point in even trying this.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it like so:

```
function changeOpacity(i){
  setInterval(function(){
  if(i>0){
    percenti= i/100;
 $(".div").css("opacity",percenti);
    i--;
    }
  },100);
}
changeOpacity(10);
```

You can find full source [here](http://jsbin.com/wuhovaha/1/)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to consider here:

**1. You can't output any HTML before a header() function call.**

This will throw something like the following:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /some/file.php:12) in /some/file.php on line 23
```

You will need to look at JavaScript re-directs after your animation is complete or potentially output buffering.

**2. You need to learn the difference between server side and client side scripting**

What you are trying to achieve is not possible in PHP, as in you will paste all your CSS code out but only the final value will be used for the CSS, overwriting the previous rules pasted on your page, no animation.

You can learn more [on this page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming) about the differences.

**3. Look at keyframes in CSS**

You can achieve opacity animations using [keyframes and animations in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes), however be aware it is not supported in all browsers, it works pretty well though in those that do support it.

An example below:

```
@keyframes changeOpacity {
    from { opacity:0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}

#loginForm{

    animation: changeOpacity 1s;

}
```

**4. Look at jQuery/JavaScript**

I know you said you wanted to avoid using JavaScript/jQuery, and apart from keyframes you are out of luck. The jQuery route will be more cross browser compatible and you will need the addition jQuery UI to perform animations but you could [check them out on this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

An example below:

```
$( "#loginForm" ).animate( {opacity: "1" }, 1000 );
```

I hope this begins to point you in the right direction on what to consider to achieve this.